# What is the difference between "stressed" and "stressful"?

Tags: adjectives, word-difference

"Stressed" and "Stressful"

are these two words both adjectives?

And what is the difference between the two?

In the dictionary it says:

> stressed - feeling very worried or anxious.
>
> stressful - full of or causing stress.

If you are worried or anxious, then aren't you full of stress?

So do these two sentences mean the same thing?

- I am very stressed.
- I am very stressful.

Comment: "Stressed" can also be used to refer to materials that carry a load. "Stress" is an engineering concept, and materials like steel can become "stressed"

Answer (score 6):

You are correct that both are adjectives, but both carry different meanings.

[stressed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stressed) - feeling very worried or anxious.

[stressful](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stressful) - full of or causing stress.

Events or circumstances can be **stressful**, in that they cause somebody to feel **stressed**. In short, one is *cause*, and one is *effect*.

For example:

> - I had a **stressful** day at work today. *(the day was stressful)*
> - I was feeling pretty **stressed** because of the deadline at work today. *(I felt stress because of work)*

Comment: Is it common or is it OK to say: I have stress instead of I've got stressed? Do they carry the same meaning?

Comment: It is ok, but not common, to say "I have stress."  "I am stressed (out)" is the common phrase.  It would be common to say "I have stress *at work*" to describe a habitual situation.